# Merge two data frames by begin and end dates

Tags: r

I have two data frames, each one of the two has a begin and end date. Does anyone know how to merge the two in order to have the common time windows?

the shape of each data frame is

**id**  |  **begin_date**  |  **end_date**

xxx     | xxxx/xx/xx       |     xxxx/xx/xx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You might want to look into the [`foverlaps` function of the `data.table` package](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+data.table+foverlaps+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I think I found a way to do it... I have some results and i need to check if it's what i need. Indeed, i am new on StackOverflow... I used to read some posts but i'll read the guide to ask good questions.